# Very simple video editor

Tags: windows, software-rec, video-editing

First of all, I must to say that I don't know anything about video editing. I'm a total noob in this field.

I need to make a screencast. Actually, I have made the desktop recording and I have some shorts videos in mp4 format to work with it. Thats what I need:

1. Cut some fragments of the videos
2. Join the selected portions into a
   big video
3. Make some transicions in  the
   cutting points (A simple fade will
   do the job)
4. Put some text in the bottom of the
   videos during a few seconds making
   explanations
5. Adding fragments of sound from a
   mp3/wav record

That's all... Which "very simple" video editor could I use?

Comment: Windows Movie Maker is simple (sometimes too simple), but as far as I know can do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'm downloading it. Please, put your comment as an answer, and I will accept it if this is the software i'm looking for. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [Windows Movie Maker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Movie_Maker), it's free, made by Microsoft for Windows, is made to serve "dummies" and does everything you need.

If you have **Windows XP**, it should already be installed in your computer, look for it in: `Start > Programs > Accessories`.

If wou've got **Windows 7 or Windows Vista**, it comes with the Windows Live suite. You can download it [here](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-movie-maker?os=other).

Windows Movie Maker:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: doesn't support MPEG4 afaik

Answer (score 2):

Sony Vegas will surely fits your needs: I found it very funny and intuitive (being a total noob at video editing!)

Comment: I think $542 is a bit expensive for Sony Vegas Pro which has the same value to the OP as Windows Movie Maker...

Answer (score 0):

iMovie is amazingly good, and comes with your Mac, or is £2.99 on your iPad2.