# Video Editing Software for Windows OS

Tags: windows, software-rec, video-editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Very simple video editor](https://superuser.com/questions/251145/very-simple-video-editor)

I want to modify the text inside video, can anyone please recommend the software which can modify the frame of video? I am using windows operating system? If its not possible then please tell the software which can blur the particular portion of video.

Comment: @BloodPhilia I have to modify the frames inside video and I think window movie maker can't do this.

Comment: @Arman There's another suggestions (answer) to the dupe question that WILL do that... Sony Vegas.

Comment: @BloodPhilia I haven't use Sony Vegas before. What do you think Sony Vegas can resolve my problem?

Comment: @Arman I'm pretty sure it can, I use WMM for all simple edits and Sony Vegas Pro for all the things WMM can't do. I know for a fact you can blur an area, as I have done this with someone's face once.

Comment: Ok BloodPhilia thanks a lot for your suggestion. I'll try your recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can't do that.  If you want to take a finished video which includes "super" text (text on top of the video) and you do not have the separate video file without the text available, it is not practical to change the text to be different text. You can blur it or cover it with a colored box, but you can't change it to be different letters.

If you want to change *subtitles*, on the other hand, many video packages can do that.  If so, please edit your question to explain exactly what you want to do.

EDIT: Having read your comments: almost any video editor can blur a portion of the screen. My former employer (with which I have no current business relationship) has an article on their web site that might be helpful: http://www.deskshare.com/resources/articles/vem_watermark_videos.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a freeware video processing utility like VirtualDub, for which there are several filters available for free download (try neuron2.net). Either the box blur or delogo filter can do what you want.